# Excel VBA does not compile - MD5 hash function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2011

Right now trying to implement a VBA module in Excel 2011 for Mac I found through the interwebs. The following module fails on the third line where you see `As String`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MD5Hash( _
  ByVal strText As String) _
  As String

' Create and return MD5 signature from strText.
' Signature has a length of 32 characters.
'
' 2005-11-21. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim cMD5          As New clsMD5
  Dim strSignature  As String

  ' Calculate MD5 hash.
  strSignature = cMD5.MD5(strText)

  ' Return MD5 signature.
  MD5Hash = strSignature

  Set cMD5 = Nothing

End Function

Public Function IsMD5( _
  ByVal strText As String, _
  ByVal strMD5 As String) _
  As Boolean

' Checks if strMD5 is the MD5 signature of strText.
' Returns True if they match.
' Note: strText is case sensitive while strMD5 is not.
'
' 2005-11-21. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim booMatch  As Boolean

  booMatch = (StrComp(strMD5, MD5Hash(strText), vbTextCompare) = 0)
  IsMD5 = booMatch

End Function
```

[image: VBA compiler error]

Hopefully someone can help chime in, since this is my first time playing with VBA. Appreciate the help!

**Update**

The error message text:

> User-defined type not defined

Comment: Have you tried removing the line continuations? Also what is the error?

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: Whoops sorry @cronos2546 @Alexandre the error message is `User-defined type not defined` and I've actually fixed this problem, adding the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, looks like my lack of knowledge of the interface with VBA. Turns out my `Class Module` was not named properly. I ended up rebuilding the module from scratch and VBA was able to give me a different error on a different line, pointing to a reference to `clsMD5`. Here's how I fixed it:

1) Open the VBA "window" by pressing `alt+F11`

2) Use the "Properties" window to edit the name of the class module, in the problem above I needed to change the name to `clsMD5`

[image: Properties window VBA]